# how to make a php array

Tags: php, arrays

I tried transfer `$str` to be an array group.

```
$str = '1,2,3,4,5';
print_r(array($str)); //this get  Array ( [0] => 1,2,3,4,5 )
```

I tried `compact`

```
print_r(array(compact($str))); // Array ( [0] => Array ( ) )
```

but how to make `$str` to be

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with:

```
$str = array(1,2,3,4,5);
```

Otherwise, if you mean that your input is '1,2,3,4,5' then use explode:

```
$str = explode(',', '1,2,3,4,5');
```

In both cases the output of **print_r($str);** is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
)
```

Answer (score 8):

You should try to use `explode` keyword.

```
$str = '1,2,3,4,5';
print_r(explode(',', $str));
```

Should print:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @stivlo's answer, you can do this to break a string into an array:

```
$str = '1,2,3,4,5';
$array = explode(',', $str);
```

[`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split) is also an option for more complicated splitting situations.

Answer (score 1):

Try `explode(',',$str)`.

Or better yet, `array_map('intval',explode(',',$str))` if you want integers.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the [explode function](http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)?

```
$arr = explode(",", $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `explode()` to split the string into array, if the $str must be a string. Or declare it as `array`.